# Setting up karma for every angular component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am currently trying to set up karma for each and every component of my angular app, and I can't find a proper explanation of the setup.

Is is possible in one file to import every Component, Service, Directive to not have to import them in every test file so that every .spec file contains only the tests themselves ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think there is a way but Angular test component by component.

Strongly advice to read https://angular.io/guide/testing#try-the-live-example

You can make your own module import all other components there and create the component (like a parent) for testing.